# Especificar la ubcación de un modelo en laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel-5

Saludo,

Para tener más organizado los modelos de laravel 5.8 quiero crear una carpeta específica que no todos queden debajo de /app, es decir, los modelos asociodos a admin queden en /app/modelos/admin, los asociados al blog queden /app/modelos/blogs, y así según se requiera.

Cómo logro especificar cada ubicación?

Answer (score 1):

En principio solo tienes que crear la carpeta dentro de App y cuando quieras usarla en algún controlador, solo tendrás que indicar la carpeta en la que se encuentra cuando lo incluyas através de *use*. Es decir, cambiar:

```
use App\Usuario;
```

por

```
use App\modelos\admin\Usuario;
```

Comment: En la documentación dice "Para empezar, vamos a crear un modelo de Eloquent. Los modelos residen típicamente en el directorio app, pero eres libre de colocarlos en cualquier parte que pueda ser auto-cargada de acuerdo a tu archivo composer.json." Hay que hacer algo en el archivo composer.json?